# Prove or disprove that $ \min\Bigg\{\frac{2x(1+\cos\theta)}{x+y},\frac{2x(1-\cos\theta)}{x-y}\Bigg\}\leq 2.$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution

Let $x>0$, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that  $|y|<x$. Prove or disprove by counterexample that
\begin{equation}
\min\Bigg\{\frac{2x(1+\cos\theta)}{x+y},\frac{2x(1-\cos\theta)}{x-y}\Bigg\}\leq 2.
\end{equation}
 I faced it in a research problem and confirmed it numerically.

Comment: $x=1,y=0,\theta=\pi/2$

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\min\left\{\frac{2x(1+\cos\theta)}{x+y},\frac{2x(1-\cos\theta)}{x-y}\right\}=k.$$
Thus, $$\frac{2x(1+\cos\theta)}{x+y}\geq k$$ and $$\frac{2x(1-\cos\theta)}{x-y}\geq k$$ or
$$1+\cos\theta\geq k\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y}{2x}\right)$$ and
$$1-\cos\theta\geq k\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{2x}\right),$$ which after summing gives
$$2\geq k$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by end it? It seems done to me.

Comment: @krms It was a joke. Sorry. Can you post your attempts? Otherwise, this topic would be deleted.

Comment: Well, this was not a homework question. I faced it in a research problem and confirmed it numerically.